# C# - Custom Attributes

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, attributes

I want to log all calls to all class methods with a specific attribute. How would i do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
class ExecutionLogAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class Human
{
    private Int32 age;

    [ExecutionLog]
    public void HaveBirthday()
    {
        age++;
    }
}
```

What would now be the best way to log all calls to HaveBirthday?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple answer: [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/). More complex one: [Spring.NET](http://springframework.net/) or custom AOP (this is what you need: Aspect-Oriented Programming) implementation using [ContextBoundObject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/aopsimplestscenario.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm going to look in to that!

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to PostSharp. It looks really simple.